# Javascript check if decimal of HTML form field is .0 or .5

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that fires on change of an HTML form field which simply adds a decimal (.0) to the inputted number and checks that the value entered is between 1 and 100. It works fine but now I need to alter my function to also check that the decimal inputted is either .0 or .5 and refuse if it does not match. This is my code:

```
     function wingsetDecimal(input) {
              input.value = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(1);
              if (input.value <1 || input.value >100) {
                  alert("Wing Length value is above or below limits");
// accept the value and do not reset field
// input.value ='';
            }
         }
```

I don't know how to approach this issue to check if the decimal part is .0 or .5. In other words the field should be reset `input.value =''` if the value inputted is, for example 10.4 but accepted if it is 10.0 or 10.5. I have tried with `string.indexOf(".")==-1;` to no success.

Comment: Hint: `num % 1` gives you the decimal part, ie, `10.4 % 1` is (almost) `0.4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my two cents, but perhaps this would do the trick:

```
if ((input.value % 1) * 10 === 0 || (input.value % 1) * 10 === 5) {
    // logic comes 'ere
}
```

Or as Derek has pointed out in the comments, it works in an ever shorter form:

```
if(!(input.value % 0.5)) {
    // todo
}}
```

Comment: Even shorter `if(!((input.value % 1) % 0.5))`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 that's a very nice and short alternative. Hope you don't mind if I update my answer with it.

Comment: By the way, the `%1` isn't even needed I believe after a second thought

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!(input.value * 2 % 1)) {
    //there ya go
}
```

Comment: or as someone mentioned below:  !(input.value %0.5) is actually even more elegant.